# Having 1 distinct column and a sum value from another column

Tags: sql, plsql

I would like to have a solution to this question:

I have a datatable here, as shown below

```
       cid                  amount
        1                     5
        1                     10   
        2                     2
        3                     5
        3                     7
        3                     11
```

Now I need to write a statement that returns a distinct cid, and the sum of the amount column for each cid. The table should look as below:

```
       cid                   amount
        1                      15
        2                       2
        3                      23
```

What is the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
select cid, sum(amount) amount from table group by cid
```

Comment: nice and fast.................

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
select cid, sum(amount)
from tab
group by cid
```

Comment: nice..........................

Answer (score 1):

```
select cid, sum(amount)
 from table_name
group by cid;
```

Comment: nice........................

Answer (score 0):

select cid,sum(amount) from c1 group by cid